# How to pass data from one router to another in ExpressJS and multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

i have the following code:

```
router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers['authorization'];
  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Failed to authenticate',
        error: err
      });
    } else {
      req.decoded = decoded;
    }
    next();
  });
})

var _storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    var dest = './express-server/uploads/users/'  + req.decoded.user._id;
    var stat = null;
    try {
      stat = fs.statSync(dest);
    }
    catch (err) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dest);
    }
    if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
      throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
    }
    cb(null, dest )
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(2, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + '.' + file.originalname.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
});  

var upload = multer({storage: _storage});
imageType = upload.single('fileUpload');

router.post('/upload', imageType, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file.path)  // this logs out the path
  res.send({success:true);
});
```

So far so good, the image gets uploaded from frontend and it's stored correctly in the file system.

Right below this route, i got another route:

```
router.post('/new', function ( req, res,  next) {
  var token = req.headers['authorization'];
  var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
  User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        title: 'An error occured',
        err: err
      });
    }

    var person = new Person({
      name: req.body.name,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      imageURL: **// how i can grab the uploaded file path inside this route from the upload route? Is this even possible?**,
      user: doc
    })
```

After this code i save the form in Mongodb without any issues, i just cant grab the filename path.

```
Person.save(function (err, newPerson) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          title: 'An error occured',
          err: err
        });
      }
      doc.person.push(newPerson);
      doc.save();
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Person Saved!',
        obj: newPerson
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a functioning image save step in your middleware or route handlers, the best thing to do is add the public URL to that uploaded file to the user object for saving later.

I strongly advise against methods that suggest storing the whole image as a buffer in your database.  While that's possible to do, it'll put more load on your server than sending a static file from disk, and there are low cost options for static file handling (e.g. CDNs) that you'll not be able to use if you store in a db.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to take the file that was uploaded with your current setup.

What I would do, If I were you is to save the uploads of the user in the database as well.

```
router.post('/upload', imageType, function (req, res, next) {

  User.findById(req.decoded.user._id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) { return res.status(500).send("Internal server error") }
    doc.file = req.file;
    doc.save( function( err ) { res.send( { success: true } ) }
  } );

});
```

And then in your route

```
router.post('/new', function ( req, res,  next) {
  var token = req.headers['authorization'];
  var decoded = jwt.decode(token);
  User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        title: 'An error occured',
        err: err
      });
    }

    var person = new Person({
      name: req.body.name,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      imageURL: doc.file.path
      user: doc
    });
} );
```